# Как бесплатно на macbook m1 установить виртуальную машину

Tags: macos, виртуальная-машина

Cегодня взял macbook m1 и пытался поставить на него virtualbox,но без успешно.Сделайте пожалуйста рекомендацию бесплатного программного обеспечение для macOS.

Comment: Расскажите о своих впечатлениях о маке, пожалуйста. Тоже хочу купить. У вас pro или air?

Comment: @entithat У меня macbook pro 13 на 512 gb памяти и 16 gb оперативной памяти. Отлично подходит для работы. Рекомендую взять pro версию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как у вас не получается поставить virtualbox на вашу машину,могу порекомендовать данный софт:

https://mac.getutm.app/

В случае,если вы качаете из сайта то она бесплатная.

Answer (score 0):

Можно установить тестовый билд VirtualBox здесь по ссылке https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds и там ищите macOS/ARM64 BETA

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).